# C programming -> wpa_supplicant connected -> udp broadcast sendto "Network Unreachable"

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I have been stuck for a couple of weeks on sending broadcast package to detect dhcp server (255.255.255.255 to port 67).

If somebody could take the time to discover my flaw in the thinking process, I'd appreciate it.

### Step 1 : Preparing my system to build dhcp client myself

I made shellscript to kill dhcpd and disconnect my Wifi and connect again using wpa_supplicant

```
echo "Killing DHCP daemon to open up port 68"
sudo killall -TERM dhcpcd dhclient

echo "Stopping Network Service"
sudo /etc/init.d/network stop

echo "Ifdown on network interfaces"
sudo /sbin/ifconfig eth0 down
sudo /sbin/ifconfig wlan0 down

echo "Connecting to Wifi using WPA_Supplicant"
sudo /usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant -Dwext -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf &
```

### Step 2 : Check that wireless connection is ok

```
user@suse:sudo /usr/sbin/wpa_cli status
root's password:
Selected interface 'wlan0'
bssid=5c:35:3b:64:79:59
ssid=Joehoe
id=0
mode=station
pairwise_cipher=TKIP
group_cipher=TKIP
key_mgmt=WPA2-PSK
wpa_state=COMPLETED
address=00:26:c7:1e:a2:42
```

### Step 3 : Bumping into my problem

Side note : if running /usr/sbin/dhclient at this point works fine, so i make conclusion that wireless really is fine

I run the following code :

```
/** Compile : gcc -m32 dhcpclient.c -o dhcpclient */
#define DHCPSERVERPORT 67
#define DHCPCLIENTPORT 68

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/******************************************************************/
/************ DHCP Message Structure  ********************/

typedef struct {
   unsigned char op;                       // Message opcode/type   // unsigned char can be replaced by uint8_t, see C manual for info
  unsigned char htype;                    // Hardware addr type
  unsigned char hlen;                     // Hardware addr length
  unsigned char hops;                     // Number of relay agent hops from client
  unsigned long xid;                      // Transaction ID
  unsigned short secs;                    // Seconds since client started looking
  unsigned short flags;                   // Flag bits
  struct in_addr ciaddr;                  // Client IP address (if already in use)
  struct in_addr yiaddr;                  // Client IP address
  struct in_addr siaddr;                  // IP address of next server to talk to
  struct in_addr giaddr;                  // DHCP relay agent IP address
  unsigned char chaddr[16];               // Client hardware address
  char sname[64];                         // Server name
  char file[128];                         // Boot filename
  char magiccookie[4];                    // DHCP option cookie
  char options[59];                       // Optional parameters (actual length dependent on MTU).
} dhcp_msg;


/************ DHCP DISCOVER  ********************/
dhcp_msg dhcpdiscover(){ 

    //struct dhcp_msg dhcpdiscover;
    dhcp_msg dhcpdiscover;
    dhcpdiscover.op = 1;
    dhcpdiscover.htype = 1;
    dhcpdiscover.hlen = 6;
    dhcpdiscover.hops = 0;
    dhcpdiscover.xid = 0;
    dhcpdiscover.secs = 0;
    dhcpdiscover.flags = 0;
    dhcpdiscover.ciaddr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    dhcpdiscover.yiaddr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    dhcpdiscover.siaddr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    dhcpdiscover.giaddr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
        dhcpdiscover.chaddr[0] = 0x00;
        dhcpdiscover.chaddr[1] = 0x26;
        dhcpdiscover.chaddr[2] = 0xC7;
        dhcpdiscover.chaddr[3] = 0x1E;
        dhcpdiscover.chaddr[4] = 0xA2;
        dhcpdiscover.chaddr[5] = 0x42;
    dhcpdiscover.chaddr[6] = 0x00;
    dhcpdiscover.chaddr[7] = 0x00;
    dhcpdiscover.chaddr[8] = 0x00;
    dhcpdiscover.chaddr[9] = 0x00;
    dhcpdiscover.chaddr[10] = 0x00;
    dhcpdiscover.chaddr[11] = 0x00;
    dhcpdiscover.chaddr[12] = 0x00;
    dhcpdiscover.chaddr[13] = 0x00;
    dhcpdiscover.chaddr[14] = 0x00;
    dhcpdiscover.chaddr[15] = 0x00;
    memset(dhcpdiscover.sname,0,sizeof(dhcpdiscover.sname));
    memset(dhcpdiscover.file,0,sizeof(dhcpdiscover.file));
/************   setting magiccookie and options to 0 -> recognized as BootP protocol ***/
    dhcpdiscover.magiccookie[0] = 99;
    dhcpdiscover.magiccookie[1] = 130;
    dhcpdiscover.magiccookie[2] = 83;
    dhcpdiscover.magiccookie[3] = 99;
    dhcpdiscover.options[0] = 53;
    dhcpdiscover.options[1] = 1;
    dhcpdiscover.options[2] = 1;
    dhcpdiscover.options[3] = 255;
/** always set 0xff as DHCP End option to close option listing, rest is padding **/


    return dhcpdiscover;
}

void printDHCPStructure(dhcp_msg dhcpstructure){
   dhcp_msg dhcpstruct = dhcpstructure;
   printf("\n\tDHCP Field\tBytes\tValue\n");
   printf("\t----------------------------------\n");
printf("\top : \t\t1\t%x\n", dhcpstruct.op);
printf("\thtype : \t1\t%x\n", dhcpstruct.htype);
  printf("\thlen : \t\t1\t%x\n", dhcpstruct.hlen);
printf("\thops : \t\t1\t%x\n", dhcpstruct.hops);
 printf("\txid : \t\t1\t%x\n", dhcpstruct.xid);
printf("\tsecs : \t\t1\t%x\n", dhcpstruct.secs);
printf("\tflags : \t1\t%x\n", dhcpstruct.flags);
printf("\tciaddr : \t1\t%s\n", dhcpstruct.ciaddr);




printf("\tyiaddr : \t1\t%s\n", dhcpstruct.yiaddr);
printf("\tsiaddr : \t1\t%s\n", dhcpstruct.siaddr);
printf("\tgiaddr : \t1\t%s\n", dhcpstruct.giaddr);
printf("\tchadddr[MAC] : \t16\t%x:%x:%x:%x:%x:%x\n", dhcpstruct.chaddr[0],dhcpstruct.chaddr[1],dhcpstruct.chaddr[2],dhcpstruct.chaddr[3],dhcpstruct.chaddr[4],dhcpstruct.chaddr[5]);
printf("\tsname : \t64\t%s\n", dhcpstruct.sname);
printf("\tfile : \t\t128\t%s\n", dhcpstruct.file);
printf("\tmgckie_0 : \t1\t%d\n", (unsigned char)dhcpstruct.magiccookie[0]);
printf("\tmgckie_1 : \t1\t%d\n", (unsigned char)dhcpstruct.magiccookie[1]);
printf("\tmgckie_2 : \t1\t%d\n", (unsigned char)dhcpstruct.magiccookie[2]);
printf("\tmgckie_3 : \t1\t%d\n", (unsigned char)dhcpstruct.magiccookie[3]);
printf("\toptions : \t59\t\n");
printf("\n");
}


int bindBroadcastUdpv4(int socket,short int socketport)
 {
int clientsock = socket;
struct sockaddr_in udpaddr;
memset((char *)&udpaddr, 0, sizeof(udpaddr));
udpaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
udpaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
udpaddr.sin_port = htons(socketport);

if (bind(clientsock, (struct sockaddr *)&udpaddr, sizeof(udpaddr)) < 0)
{
    printf("Binding the UDP Socket failed\n");
    printf("Tip 1 : Run 'sudo netstat -l -u -n -p | grep %d'\n", socketport);
    printf("Tip 2 : Run program with root privileges\n");
    perror("Error");
    exit(1);
}
else
{
    return 1;
}
}

/******************************************************************/
/******************************************************************/

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

/** Creating UDP client socket **/
int clientsock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
int broadcastpermissions = 1;
short int clientport = DHCPCLIENTPORT;
short int destinationport = DHCPSERVERPORT;

if (clientsock < 0)
{
    perror("Error @ Step 1 : Cannot create client socket");
}
else
{
    printf("Step 1 : Client socket created succesfully\n");
}


/** Give client socket broadcast permissions **/
if (broadcastpermissions)
{
    int ret = setsockopt(clientsock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&broadcastpermissions,sizeof(broadcastpermissions));
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        printf("Error @ step 1BisA : Giving Client Socket reuse options FAILED: %d\n", ret);
        exit(0);
    }

    ret = setsockopt(clientsock,SOL_SOCKET,SO_BROADCAST,&broadcastpermissions,sizeof(broadcastpermissions));
    if (ret != 0)
    {
        printf("Error @ step 1BisB : Giving Client Socket broadcast permissions FAILED: %d\n", ret);
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\tSetting broadcast permissions on client socket succeeded\n");
    }
}

/** Binding the client socket **/
if (bindBroadcastUdpv4(clientsock, clientport))
{
    printf("Step 2 : Socket is binded succesfully\n");
}

/** Create DHCP Discovery data structure **/
dhcp_msg dhcpdiscovery = dhcpdiscover();
printf("Step 3 : DHCP Discovery Data Structure created\n");
printDHCPStructure(dhcpdiscovery);

/** Trying to broadcast to 255.255.255.255 on port 67 to detect DHCP Servers */
struct sockaddr_in destinationaddr;
memset((char *)&destinationaddr, 0, sizeof(destinationaddr));
destinationaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
//destinationaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_BROADCAST;
destinationaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_BROADCAST);
destinationaddr.sin_port = htons(destinationport);
//destinationaddr.sin_port = destinationport;


/** translate Hexadecimal notation of IP Address to decimal **/
int IP1 = (ntohl(destinationaddr.sin_addr.s_addr) >> 24) & 0xFF;
int IP2 = (ntohl(destinationaddr.sin_addr.s_addr) >> 16) & 0xFF;
int IP3 = (ntohl(destinationaddr.sin_addr.s_addr) >> 8) & 0xFF;
int IP4 = (ntohl(destinationaddr.sin_addr.s_addr)) & 0xFF;

//while(1){};

printf("DEBUG : Clientsock = %d\n", clientsock);
printf("DEBUG : .sin_addr = %p\n", destinationaddr.sin_addr.s_addr);
printf("DEBUG : .sin_port = %d\n", destinationaddr.sin_port);
printf("DEBUG : .sin_port = %d\n", destinationport);



/******************************************************************************************************************************************************************/


int a = sendto(clientsock,&dhcpdiscovery,sizeof(dhcpdiscovery),0,(struct sockaddr *)&destinationaddr, sizeof(destinationaddr));

if (a < 0)
{
    printf("A is :\%d\n", a);
    printf("UDP Message to %d.%d.%d.%d on port %d failed\n",IP1,IP2,IP3,IP4,destinationport);
    perror("Sending failed : ");
    return 667;
}
else
{
        printf("UDP Messsage to %d.%d.%d.%d on port %d SUCCESS !\n",IP1,IP2,IP3,IP4,destinationport);
}

close(clientsock);

}

/******************************************************************/
/******************************************************************/
```

Extra info :
A) as said before, when running dhclient, i get ip address assigned and wiresharks shows me dhcp conversations

B) when running my own code when ipaddress is already assigned, sending is success

C) The error returned by sendTo is 'Network Unreachable'

So my question is : i am connected to my wireless AP, which step i need to perform extra so i can have my socket send out broadcast packet ?
The reason for doing this is to learn about networks and to learn to program, so my programming skills are not awesome which is why you may see ridiculous code. I appreciate any comments on it but prefer to stick to my main problem.

Kindest regards to fellow earthlings !

Comment: Are you running your code as root?  Root privileges are usually required to sendto the broadcast address.

Comment: Hi cklin, a very nice guy 'Saravana' hinted me to the answer. For regular sockets to function, you need ip address on the interface.
AFAIK, the native dhclient would be using the raw sockets.

So, yes my code is executed as root but i am using regular sockets.
I am now verifying howto do it with raw sockets. If this is the answer, i will answer my own question here for clarity.

If, however, raw sockets are not the solution. I'll dig deeper !

Comment: I just compiled your code and it executed fine on my machine.  tcpdump shows the proper output: `10.191.17.134.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: [udp sum ok] BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 00:00:00:00:00:00, length 312, xid 0xff7f0000, Flags [none] (0x0000)
   Client-Ethernet-Address 00:00:00:00:00:00`

Comment: In any case, you shouldn't use raw sockets.  DHCP uses UDP as its transport.  Using a raw socket will just mean you have to reinvent the wheel by hand-coding your own UDP headers.

Comment: I agree, the code just runs fine when I already have ip-address assigned (on wlan0 or eth0). The problem is that when you send DHCP discover, you do not have assigned ip-address on that particular point (as you are requesting one).

So, only in that case I get 'Network Unreachable'. This is why somebody let me find the answer that I need to use the raw sockets to broadcast even with no ip-address assigned (for DHCP Discover).

Comment: Ah! Now I understand your problem.  Yes, you probably have to use raw sockets.

Answer (score 0):

I think you *do* want to use raw sockets here. Whilst it is true (as per @cklin) this means you have to reinvent the wheel somewhat, dhcp is unusual in that you are sending packets before the interface is properly configured. As a simple guide, I suggest you look at busybox and how its `dhclient` script works. Another alternative is `libpcap`. This captures replies (even ones not directly addressed to you) and has a little known feature of being able to send raw packets too. I have successfully used it to write a dhcp server.